# Removing variable from a formula in R

Tags: r, formula, linear-regression, lm

I faced the following problem while carrying out a linear regression modeling in R. I use the `Boston` dataset from the MASS package, and take the `medv` variable as the response and all others as the predictors. I found that the following two lines of code give identical results:

1. `summary(lm(medv ~ . , data = Boston))`
2. `summary(lm(Boston$medv ~ . , data = Boston))`

Next, I want to drop the variable `tax` and carry out the regression anew. Here, I found that the analogous lines of code yield different outputs:

1. `summary(lm(medv ~ . - tax, data = Boston))`
2. `summary(lm(Boston$medv ~ . - Boston$tax, data = Boston))`

Not only the above two lines give different outputs, but the second line indeed fails to drop the `tax` variable, and therefore yield a wrong result. I could not understand why they behave differently.

Comment: I didn't even know you could do it the second way, the first is faster to type

Comment: How is a function  to know that `Boston$tax` in the formula is the same as the `tax` variable from the dataset supplied to its `data` argument?

Comment: I don't know @Roland, I just typed the analogous formulations of the two lines of code from the first part.

Comment: Obviously, it can't know that unless it is checked (which is not easy to implement in a general way and not useful since you can and should just use the first option).

Comment: Maybe the function is looking for something like `Boston$Boston$tax`?

Comment: But, @Ronald, for the response part, there seems to be no problem in either `medv` or `Boston$medv`; both are treated as the same.

Comment: @grouah No, it isn't: `model.matrix(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + iris$Sepal.Width, data = iris)`

Comment: @joy Because they contain the same values. Just use always the two first options. Otherwise you can encounter other issues with subsequent functions that use `lm` objects.

Comment: This for some reason works `summary(lm(Boston$medv ~ . - tax, data = Boston))
` still ugly to look at but it works

Comment: `tt <- terms(demand ~ Time - BOD$Time, data = BOD); attr(tt, "variables")`  shows that it thinks that `Time` and `BOD$Time` are distinct variables (where `BOD` is a data frame that comes with R) supporting what @Roland stated.